# What is to be studied in order to a complete newbie proficiently implement Comet?

Tags: frameworks, comet, infrastructure

Okay. I know this is going to hurt.

I have some background in HTML, CSS and JavaScript, Ajax included. I (somewhat) know how to handle PHP and make it send queries to MySQL through an Apache server. In other words, I've been learning web development, or part of it, for the last few months. I've also studied a little bit of OOP. This is it.

But now I want to develop some JavaScript-based online multiplayer games. I don't want to make use of Java applets nor Flash/Shockwave/etc. -- as far as I understand it, I don't like their disadvantages, and their advantages don't appeal me enough. I know JavaScript has its cons as well, yes.

And so it seems that Comet is the way for what I plan. I think I understand the concept -- or at least I think I understand it enough to have chosen the long-polling technique to build the online games on.

After more than a week reading posts and articles and tutorials, the only thing I've found out is that there's a lot to learn. Apparently, I've got to learn how the whole web infrastructure works. Queues, threads, daemons, event-driven frameworks -- I don't even know if I'm using the correct terms. I'm (almost) completely lost.

So where do I start? Which languages to learn, which books to read? I consider myself diligent, so don't be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

Which language to use, is your choice. In many of them you will have a Comet implementation: Java, Python, Ruby, PHP, etc.

And first of all it depends on what do you want to build.

I am using Comet with Java for financial market, but for games or webapps, It's not the better choice.

So, in fact you have to choose some language/platform after study a little bit of them, and then use Comet with your chosen one.

Comment: And BTW, I would recommend Python ;-)